# Angular Testing: TestBed doesn't require providing ApplicationRef

Tags: angular, testing

I'm following along the official 'testing' guide at https://angular.io/guide/testing writing tests for an application.

As I'm testing a service with dependencies, I need to provide mocks for these dependencies, but interestingly this does not seem to be true for ApplicationRef, and I'd really like to know why.

The service is something like this:

```
export class MyService {

    constructor(
        private dependentService: DependentService,
        private applicationRef:ApplicationRef
    ){}
    ...
```

and the corresponding test spec:

```
describe('MyService', () => {
    let dependentServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<HttpClient>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const dependentServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('DependentService', ['test']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            // Provide both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency
            // why is 'ApplicationRef' not needed here?? 
            providers: [
                MyService,
                { provide: DependentService, useValue: dependentService_spy }
            ]
        });
    });
    ...   

});
```

As both 'DependentService' and 'ApplicationRef' are injected in the MyService constructor, i'd expect both are needed in the TestBed's providers array. But while leaving out 'DependentService' yields an error in tests, **the missing 'ApplicationRef' does not**.

Is there some reasonable explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Angular testing configuration, that uses TestBed, starts with the following initialization:

```
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
```

Angular testing environment will use BrowserDynamicTestingModule to construct injector as it works for ordinary Angular modules (see also https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-dependency-injection-and-tree-shakeable-tokens-4588a8f70d5d).

Angular merges providers that `BrowserDynamicTestingModule` contain. This module is declared as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [BrowserTestingModule],
  providers: [
    {provide: TestComponentRenderer, useClass: DOMTestComponentRenderer},
  ]
})
export class BrowserDynamicTestingModule {
}
```

where `BrowserTestingModule` looks like:

```
                /\
                ||

@NgModule({
  exports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_ID, useValue: 'a'},
    ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS,
    {provide: NgZone, useFactory: createNgZone},
  ]
})
export class BrowserTestingModule {
}
```

and `BrowserModule` is:

```
                /\
                ||             

@NgModule({providers: BROWSER_MODULE_PROVIDERS, exports: [CommonModule, ApplicationModule]})
export class BrowserModule {
  ...
}
```

and finally `ApplicationModule` declares `ApplicationRef`:

```
                 /\
                 ||

export const APPLICATION_MODULE_PROVIDERS: StaticProvider[] = [
  {
    provide: ApplicationRef,
    useClass: ApplicationRef,
    deps:
        [NgZone, Console, Injector, ErrorHandler, ComponentFactoryResolver, ApplicationInitStatus]
  },
  ...
];


@NgModule({providers: APPLICATION_MODULE_PROVIDERS})
export class ApplicationModule {
  // Inject ApplicationRef to make it eager...
  constructor(appRef: ApplicationRef) {}
}
```

and as you can see `ApplicationRef` provider is also eagerly instantiated.

This way there is no magic here, Angular just uses the same algorithm as if it would resolve providers from user-defined NgModules

Comment: Although i don't completely understand Angulars mechanisms here (yet), this answer definitely answers my question in a very profound way, so accepting it

Answer (score 1):

I have to guess, but i think:

Every component has the change detection implicitly in it. If not, no automatic change detection would work.
But to use this functionality in your code directly, you have to explicitly "catch" that service in the constructor.

Now, our TestBed will create those services that you define there explicitly. But it will also create all those internaly needed services (like ChangeDetection, see the classic "fixture.detectChanges()").
Therefore, you don´t have to create it explicitly.

The "DependentService" you mentioned is not part of the internal Angular magic, therfore you have to name it explicitly in the TestBed.

warm regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this basically seems to nail it, the answer by @yurzui just goes more into detail

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because, we inject `ApplicationRef` inside the `constructor` without providing it anywhere. And that's a normal `interface` but not a `provider`. We only provide the `providers` inside test `providers` array and not all that we have injected.
This is also true for `ChangeDetectorRef`. We never provide that inside `providers` array.

Comment: Does make sense to me, as my app code doesn't provide ApplicationRef anyhwere (and the docs list it as an 'Interface', as you mentioned). Answer by @yourzui just seems to be a bit more elaborated. I have to admit, I just don't grasp this whole dependency injection stuff yet...